# How to trigger a JavaScript function when there are values in three input elements?

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I trigger an event when there are values on three input boxes? Say for instance I have three input elements:

```
<input type = "text" name = "item1" id = "item1" value="">
<input type = "text" name = "item2" id = "item2" value="">
<input type = "text" name = "item3" id = "item3" value="">
```

I'd like to output a result using JavaScript when these three input elements have a value and automatically return null when it has not met the condition.

```
<span> item1,item2,item3 has value </span>
```

**EDIT1:**

Display the result ONLY when the 3 input boxes has values otherwise it retuns null.

**EDIT2:**
When the 3 input boxes has value i'd like to set an checkbox attr to true otherwise false when its not.

Answer (score 3):

Use `onKeyUP` event
 & check the condition if input has value `$(e).val().length>0`

## DEMO :

```js
$('input[id^=item]').keyup(function(evt){
    var hasVal=Array.from($('input[id^=item]').filter((i,e)=>$(e).val().length>0)).map((e)=>$(e).attr('id')).join(',')
      
     $('span').html((hasVal.length)?hasVal+' has value':'No input has value')

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type = "text" name = "item1" id = "item1" value="">
<input type = "text" name = "item2" id = "item2" value="">
<input type = "text" name = "item3" id = "item3" value="">
<br />
<span>  </span>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one.If you need to show you  while type in the third input means use onfocus instead of onchange in the third input.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <title>Example</title>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script>
   $(document).ready(function(){
     $('#showText').hide();
   });

   function canShowText(){
      if($('#item1').val().length>0 && $('#item2').val().length>0 && $('#item3').val().length>0)
    $('#showText').show();
   }
  </script>
 </head>
 <body>
  <input type="text" name="item1" id="item1" value="" onchange='canShowText()'><br>
  <input type="text" name="item2" id="item2" value="" onchange='canShowText()'><br>
  <input type="text" name="item3" id="item3" value="" onchange='canShowText()'><br>
  <span id='showText'> item1,item2,item3 has value </span>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: JUST EDITED IT AND HAVE IT WORK ACCORDING TO WHAT I NEED.
 <script>
   $(document).ready(function(){
    $('#showText').hide();
       });

   function canShowText(){
    if($('#item1').val().length>0 && $('#item2').val().length>0 && $('#item3').val().length>0) {
    $('#showText').show();
  }
  else {
     $('#showText').hide();
   }
  }
  </script>

Thank you!

Comment: use else for $('#showText').hide(); if any of input value become empty and again u need hide your span content.

Comment: EDITED the question

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.toArray()`, `.every()`, `input` event

```js
function handleValues() {
  alert("all three inputs have value");
  span.html(arr.map(function(el) {return el.value}).join(","))
}

function handleInput(e) {
  arr.every(function(el) {
   return el.value.length;
  }) 
  ? handleValues() 
  : !!span.html("") && alert("all three inputs do not have value");
}

var input = $("input"), arr = input.toArray(), span = $("span");

input.on("input", handleInput);

handleInput();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type = "text" name = "item1" id = "item1" value="">
<input type = "text" name = "item2" id = "item2" value="">
<input type = "text" name = "item3" id = "item3" value=""><br>
<span></span>
```